# How do I split values in a column to various columns in a csv?

Tags: pandas, csv, pyspark

I am trying to split the values in the location column to two different x and y columns in a csv file

Right now it looks like this:

```
location
[60.0, 56.0]    
[68.0, 74.0]    
[58.0, 52.0]
[63.0, 53.0]
[119.0, 79.0]
```

I want it to split the columns and get two different columns and remove the brackets so the columns look like this:

```
x           y
60          56
68          74
58          52
63          53
119         79
```

I all of these:
1.

```
df[['x', 'y']] = pd.DataFrame(df['location'].tolist(), index=df.index)
```

2. 

```
pd.concat([df[[0]], df['location'].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1
```

3. 

```
df['location'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

But recieved errors

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition with [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) and [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) :

```
df= (
      pd.read_fwf("name-path_of_your_csv.csv")
          ["location"].str.strip("[]")
                      .str.split(",", expand=True)
                      .rename(columns={0: "x", 1: "y"})
    )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

       x      y
0   60.0   56.0
1   68.0   74.0
2   58.0   52.0
3   63.0   53.0
4  119.0   79.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate way to do it:

```
df = pd.read_csv("name-path_of_your_csv.csv")
```

And then converting them to required output

```
x = []
y = []

def splits(s):
  x.append(s[0])
  y.append(s[1])

df['locations'].apply(splits)

df['X'] = x
df['Y'] = y

# converting them to int
df['X'].astype(int)
df['Y'].astype(int)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting such an error: `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key` your row values ​​are of string type. To avoid this, you should convert them to list type:

```
import ast
df['location']=df['location'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Now let's try the method you actually did right:

```
df[['x', 'y']] = pd.DataFrame(df['location'].tolist(), index=df.index)

'''
        location      x     y
0   [60.0, 56.0]   60.0  56.0
1   [68.0, 74.0]   68.0  74.0
2   [58.0, 52.0]   58.0  52.0
3   [63.0, 53.0]   63.0  53.0
4  [119.0, 79.0]  119.0  79.0
'''
```

As an alternative, you can also use this:

```
df2 = df['location'].apply(pd.Series)
'''
       0     1
0   60.0  56.0
1   68.0  74.0
2   58.0  52.0
3   63.0  53.0
4  119.0  79.0
'''
```

or:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':[x[0] for x in df.location],'y':[x[1] for x in df.location]})
'''
    x       y
0   60.0    56.0
1   68.0    74.0
2   58.0    52.0
3   63.0    53.0
4   119.0   79.0

'''
```